# Einbein fields a very simple sketch

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

I am trying to understand something very simple, the einbein field formalism. Can someone write a down to earth step by step play of simple example say the canonical $$L = - m \sqrt{\dot{x}^2}\tag{1.1}$$ case (described in link).  I have done some digging around and found [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9611361). I don't want to look at it again. How does one come up with an einbein (auxiliary?) field. I am asking because I have seen this sort of strategy at a lot of places recently. If it is possible can we just do an analog with something that looks like a  quadratic equation and keep physics lingo away?

Comment: So I have been reading about Helmholtz conditions, Jacobi multipliers and I think I know the secret. Can someone tell me if I am in the right area? please don't use physics lingo for now.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4188/2451 . More on [einbein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=einbein).

Comment: oh nice! Also, I downloaded the reference([2] in the paper) and found a lucid exposition of the idea. pretty neat! So i guess I know 3 reasons to us this technique now.

Comment: Actually, in [2] what happened between 2.13 an 2.14 . Just want some reassurance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Step 1. Start with a constrained Hamiltonian system.

$$ S[x, p, e] = \int d\tau \left( p_{\mu} \dot{x}^{\mu} - \frac{e}{2} \left( p^2 - m^2 \right) \right). $$

This is just a constrained Hamiltonian system, the constraint being the mass-shell condition $p^2 = m^2$.

#### Step 2. Solve the (algebraic) e.o.m. for the canonical momenta $p_{\mu}$ and plug it in the action.

$$ p_{\mu} = \dot{x}_{\mu} / e,$$
$$ S[x,e] = \frac{1}{2} \int d\tau \left( e^{-1} \dot{x}^2 + e m^2 \right). $$

This is your desired form of the action I believe. $e$ plays the role of the Einbein field. This can be seen as follows: remember how the diffeo-invariant 4d integrals look in General Relativity? You sort of do the same thing in 1d where the metric tensor has only one component called $g_{\tau \tau} = e^2$. The integral is then

$$ \int d\tau \sqrt{g_{\tau \tau}} \left(g^{\tau \tau} \partial_{\tau} x \partial_{\tau} x + m^2 \right) = \int d\tau \left( e^{-1} \dot{x}^2 + e m^2 \right). $$

Note that $g_{\tau \tau} = e^2;\; \sqrt{g_{\tau \tau}} = e;\; g^{\tau \tau} = e^{-2}$ (I am assuming that $e$ is positive here).

#### Step 3. Check that the usual form of the action is implied by $S[x,e]$.

Solve the algebraic e.o.m. for $e$ with respect to $e$ and plug the result back in $S[x,e]$. I trust you to do this calculation. The end result is

$$ S[x] = -m \int d\tau \sqrt{\dot{x}^2}, $$

which coincides with what you would expect.

Comment: So we are constraining the Hamiltonian so that the solutions are in accord with points on the mass hyperboloid.  The action is then marched through standard mechanics. I see . .

Comment: @Cows that's right, and you can upvote and accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: @ Prof. Legolasov, if the constraint is $p^2 = m^2$, then $e$ looks like a Lagrange multiplier in the first equation. Does this interpretation make any sense?

Comment: @Quillo yes, the Einbein is the Lagrange multiplier fixing the mass shell constraint.